# Objective C - How to create rtf from NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, objective-c, rtf, nsattributedstring

I can convert from rtf string to attributed string using following:

```
 NSAttributedString *attributedStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:data options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSRTFTextDocumentType} documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
```

Now how can i convert back from attributedString to rtf string?

Comment: If there is no method to do so, then I doubt you can.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You want to use -dataFromRange:documentAttributes:error:

```
NSAttributedString *str = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"YOLO" attributes:nil];
NSData *data = [str dataFromRange:(NSRange){0, [str length]} documentAttributes:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSRTFTextDocumentType} error:NULL];
[data writeToFile:@"/me.rtf" atomically:YES];
```

Of course you'd want to have some attributes instead of "YOLO", but you get the idea.

Also, if you're looking to simply write this to disk, then fileWrapperFromRange:documentAttributes:error:
might even be a better option. You can find more about reading and writing from the [Attributed String Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AttributedStrings/Articles/HTMLFilesandAttributedStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014062-SW1)

Comment: I Used NSDictionary *documentAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:NSRTFTextDocumentType ,NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute, nil];
        NSData *rtfData = [txtView.attributedText dataFromRange:NSMakeRange(0, txtView.attributedText.length) documentAttributes:documentAttributes error:NULL];
        NSString *rtfString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:rtfData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

Comment: @ghazi_jaffary That's what I'm here for