# Send and Receive NSAttributedString to a server using AFNetworking

Tags: ios, afnetworking, nsattributedstring

I'm building a Social App where users can post a blog with content of type `NSAttributedString` (supporting Text-color, Bold, Italic,..). How should I send this `NSAttributedString` content to Server, so that when I receive it, I can populate it to the `UITextview` without any lost in decoration (Text-color, Bold, Italic, ..).

I tried sending an `NSString`to server, but no luck, the text I received back is something unreadable when using `[UITextView setAttributedString]`.

I guess there should be some kinds of encode and decode right?

Comment: This is tagged iOS but you reference `NSTextView`. Do you mean OS X or `UITextView`?

Comment: ah right! i'm doing mac app at day and iOS at night so my bad :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSAttributedString` conforms to NSCoding, so you can convert an NSAttributedString back and forth to NSData. It's been a while since I've used AFNetworking, but doesn't it have a way to transfer binary data? That seems like your best bet.

(`NSAttributedString` also has the ability to read from .rtf files on both Mac and iOS >= 7.0.

According to [**this thread on SO**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24134217/objective-c-how-to-create-rtf-from-nsattributedstring) it's also possible to export the contents of an attributed string to rtf format, so that's another possibility.